# Agrupar DataFrame por Data Máxima de cada mês considerando a coluna de nome com Python

Tags: python, data, pandas

Olá!
Estou tentando agrupar um df a partir da data máxima de cada mês considerando a coluna NOME.

Tenho o seguinte data frame:

```
NOME     DATA
ABC   05/01/2023
ABC   07/01/2023
DEF   01/02/2023
DEF   09/02/2023
DEF   25/01/2023
DEF   03/01/2023
ABC   02/02/2023
```

A saída esperada seria:

```
NOME     DATA
ABC   07/01/2023
ABC   02/02/2023
DEF   25/01/2023
DEF   09/02/2023
```

Considerando para cada nome a data mais recente em cada mês.

Já tentei utilizando o groupby, grouper, drop_duplicates porém nenhum deles traz a relação considerando o nome, trás somente o último nome considerando a data mais recente.

Poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Bom dia! Preciso agrupar o dataframe considerando a data máxima de cada mês para cada nome citado na coluna "NOME", parece simples e de fato é, porém não consigo agrupar usando o groupby considerando a data máxima de cada mês, somente a data máxima pra cada nome ou a data máxima por mês sem considerar a coluna NOME.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Primeiro transformei sua coluna DATA para o formato datetime com `.to_datetime`. Depois dentro do `groupby` agrupei os dados por NOME e por mês (utilizando a função `grouper` para transformar as datas dentro de um mês em um único valor). Com o groupby montado calculei a maior data. O primeiro `reset_index` é para excluir os dados do `grouper` e o segundo é para transformar o valor NOME em coluna

```
df['DATA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATA'], dayfirst = True)
df = (
    df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="DATA", freq="1M"), 'NOME'])
      .agg(max_data= ('DATA', 'max'))
      .reset_index(level=['NOME'])
      .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
df.head()
    NOME    max_data
0   ABC     2023-01-07
1   DEF     2023-01-25
2   ABC     2023-02-02
3   DEF     2023-02-09
```

Comment: Muuuito obrigada pela ajuda! É exatamente isso que eu precisava :)

Answer (score -3):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Criar DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'NOME': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'ABC'],
                   'DATA': ['05/01/2023', '07/01/2023', '01/02/2023', '09/02/2023', '25/01/2023', '03/01/2023', '02/02/2023']})

# Converter coluna de data para tipo datetime
df['DATA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATA'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Criar coluna de mês
df['MÊS'] = df['DATA'].dt.month

# Agrupar o DataFrame pelas colunas NOME e MÊS
grouped = df.groupby(['NOME', 'MÊS'])

# Selecionar a data mais recente em cada grupo
result = grouped['DATA'].max().reset_index()

# Exibir resultado
print(result)
```